# how to create a new resources in the mdpi folder in the xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin

I feel irritating to develop the xamarin now since it is so not stable... i am intend to create splash screen for the android, however from what i seen from the xamarin documentation,however before i am able to achieve it, i need to add the resources to my project. Please see the following documentation

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/resources_in_android/part_1_-_android_resource_basics/

from the beginning the resource folder has been done to create all the mdpi , ldpi those folder... they skipped to teach us how to create those resource folder, so in the end, i tried to create a new folder which is named as drawable-mdpi and put some icon into it. In the end the files and folder name does not exist in the Resource.Designer.cs.

In the end my resources is unuseable... Google no solution

Answer (score 1):

Earlier Xamarin project template used to have all Drawable folders by default. Now the template just has the mipmap folders. You need to create all the drawable folders manually by Right Clicking Resources Folder > Add > New Folder. Give names as "`drawable-mdpi`" "`drawable-hdpi`" and so on. You can then add images to them by Right Clicking respective folders > Add > Add Files. If the Image's Id doesn't appear in `Resource.Designer.cs` file, it might be due to some build error already existing. Try cleaning and re-building. Either Resource Id will appear in `Resource.Designer.cs` or the already existing error will pop-up fixing which your issue will be resolved.

Comment: Now is the world of automate, why they cancel the auto way, it is just force the third level language programmer to second level language programming style, we are rolling back to old style

Comment: and, i am failed to create the resource id in the resource designer , rebuild no error, but nothing more to come out in the designer

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of all the folders within resources expanded ?

Answer (score 1):

I realized those documentation is the xamarin old documentation, by the default the xamarin created those folder already, however i dont know why the xamarin don't show when we create the new project and i still dont understand why only create 3 density which is hdpi, xhdpi and the xxdpi, is it the mdpi not longer use? I have no idea. However i will need to add those folder again in the project so i am able to see it.